# I am trying to log into facebook using python requests and post a status but the login post method is not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to log into facebook using python requests and post a status but the login post method is not working. can u see if im doing anything wrong, here is my code. P.S. I do not want to use a browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def login_to_facebook(username, password):
    """Logs into Facebook using the given username and password."""

    # Create a session with the Requests library.
    session = requests.Session()

    # Get the login form data.
    login_data = {
        'email': username,
        'pass': password
    }

    # POST the login data to the Facebook login endpoint. 
    response = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/login.php', data=login_data)
    response_new = session.post('https://web.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&lwv=101', data=login_data)
    print("Contacts" in response.text)

    # Check if the login was successful.
    if response.status_code >= 200:
        return session
    else:
        raise Exception('Login failed.')

if name == 'main':
    # Get the username and password from the user.
    username = "alif.alemran.2@gmail.com"
    password = "abcd"

    # Log into Facebook.
    session = login_to_facebook(username, password)

    # Do something with the logged-in session.
    # For example, you could post a status update.
    response2 = session.post('https://www.facebook.com/me/posts', data={'status': 'Hello, world!'})
    print(response2.url)
```

The purpose is to log into Facebook and post a status.

Comment: Please provide some info on the error that you are getting

Comment: there is no errors. it simply isnt getting to the desired page. after logging in, it should be the facebook homepage